# Process both encoded and decoded URI correctly

Tags: java, encoding, uri

I want that my program can correctly retrieve data by URI which can contain special characters and can be both encoded by user (e.g. `...abc%5E...`) or plain text (e.g. `...abc^...`)

I tried to use `%` as a marker to mark that URI is encoded, which causes next problem:

if plain (not encoded) URI is `abc%5E` or `abc%25` my program decodes it and tried to fetch data from wrong path. So user has to insert already encoded URI in this case. (Which conflicts with my deserved functionality)

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: If you are encoding and decoding yourself, then as an option you can stick to certain standards. As an option `URLEncoder`/`URLDecoder` from `java.net` package

Comment: I know about this classes, the main point is about making correct decisions decode URI contains `%25` or `%5E` or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely not possible (logically)

Answer (score 0):

maybe decodeURI can help:

```
alert(decodeURI("abc%5E or abc^"));
```